# Hightlight buttons on click with CSS

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I have a multiple selection and would like to be able to click on it to manage the answers on a /getmatch page. At the moment I have no visual cue that I have selected things:

[[image]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDBOv.gif)

So how to make the selection of multiple items responsive?

Here is the code from the page that gives these buttons:

```
{% extends "todo/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

   <style>
      .elements {
        display: block;
      }
      ul.items {
        display: flex;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
      }
      li.item {
        flex: 1 0 20%;
        padding: 8px;
        margin: 2px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 1px solid rgba(61, 86, 233, 0.3);
        text-align: center;
      }
      .col {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
      }
    </style>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="intro-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-lg-5 mr-auto order-lg-2">
      <h3><br>Tell me something about you... </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <section class="content-section-a">

    <div class="container">
      <dt>
        <span>Pick the keywords you want to express when wearing perfume</span>
      </dt>

    <form action = "/getmatch" method="POST">
      {% for keyword in keywords %}
        <div class="elements">
            <ul class="items ">
               <li class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                 <div class="box">
                 <div data-toogle="buttons" class="col">
                    <span>{{ keyword.title }}</span>
                 </div>
                 </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="static/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="static/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexboxgrid/6.3.1/flexboxgrid.min.css" type="text/css" >


{% endblock %}
```

I tried to add things in the balisa .

```
button:hover{background-color:orange;}

button:focus{background-color:red;}
```

But it didn't modified anything

Comment: There is no `button` tag in your template so the class is not applied. Have you tried to use `.item:hover {}` and `.item:focus {}` as selectors?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dario . It works with `.item:hover {}` but it doesn't with `.item:focus {}`

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment since i don't have the required rep points (new to stack overflow, sorry if this isn't allowed), but I am not sure what you're trying to do, if you want to give a visual cue that a button has been selected for more than one button at a time, you need to grab the list of buttons, add an event listener on click that toggles a class on/off, then add styling to that class, so that when the item has that class it has a specific style.

Edit on how to do that:
P.S i've never used Django, but i think you should do this, since the way you're doing it is generating a ul for each keyword

```
<form action = "/getmatch" method="POST">
    <div class="elements">
        <ul class="items ">
  {% for keyword in keywords %}

           <li class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
             <div class="box">
             <div data-toogle="buttons" class="col">
                <span>{{ keyword.title }}</span>
             </div>
             </div>
           </li>
  {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
  {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Now you need to select the list elements, an easier way to do this would be something called event delegation https://javascript.info/event-delegation
so create a script tag/or file and import it, inside your script you neeed the following :

```
  //Select the UL list
const myItemsList = document.querySelector(".items");

//function passed to event listener as callback, toggles the selected class if the target is a list

const toggleListClass = (event) => {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName !== "li") return;
  target.classList.toggle("highlight");
};

//Add an event listener to the ul list
myItemsList.addEventListener("click", toggleListClass);
```

Now in your css add a selector for class hightlight

```
.hightlight {
  color: whatever
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. However, I don't know yet how to do an event listener. Maybe I should add that it's a Django app developed with Python?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica check the new answar